# How to send any actions to my API by facebook-messenger API if the person isn't available?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

When a user blocks my facebook bot account I can't handle any query about this action, but I need this information on my API. I try to write to an unavailable person from Facebook Page, but I just get an error "this person isn't available right now" in front and without query to my API

How I can handle, find and check unavailables users?

I thought to handle actions from chat on application's Facebook page (Mark as Done, Delete chat, etc), but I don't know how I can to get this on my API.
[Facebook actions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKHJ1.jpg)

Comment: _“I try to write to an unavailable person from Facebook Page, but I just get an error "this person isn't available right now" in front and without query to my API”_ - and what do you get when you try to send a message to such a user via API …? I would assume that you get a similar message in the response.

Comment: The API is probably going to return one of the documented error codes, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/send-api/error-codes, likely one from the “Permission Errors” section.

Comment: when I try to send a message by API a get an error to API in return "this person isn't available right now", but when I do it from chat on facebook, like support from company page in facebook, I get an error just on chatting window
But I wanna get this error to my API too

P.S. when the customer and I chatting on chat window without bot and API in general, every single message from our conversation is going through my API and I can get it

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific event for such an action (user blocking the conversation), so your only option is to handle the person-not-avail error response and mark those users on your end.